# python regex keep lines between first and last term

Tags: python, regex

So I have a text file and there's several showing up of the string 'Continue reading the main story'. Let's say the text looks like below:

> part 1
>
> Continue reading the main story
>
> part 2
>
> Continue reading the main story
>
> part 3
>
> Continue reading the main story
>
> Continue reading the main story
>
> part 4

what I want are part2 and part3, like below:

> part 2
>
> Continue reading the main story
>
> part 3

since it is between the first occurence of 'Continue reading the main story', and the last occurence of it. Right now I have think of using the following code:

```
my_regex = re.compile("(Continue reading the main story)"+
                   ".*"+ # match as many chars as possible
                   "(Continue reading the main story)",
                   re.DOTALL)
new_str = my_regex.sub("\1\2", text)
```

However its not working. How to correct it?

Comment: To clarify, please update your post along with expected output.

Comment: Since `.*?` is a *non*-greedy match on any character, your regex will probably stop the *first* time it comes across the "Continue..." string.

Comment: sorry it should be .* which is greedy, not .*?

Comment: If you know your text does *not* begin with "Continue ..." and does *not* end with "Continue ...", you can split on the "Continue ..." string, remove the first, last and empty items, and you'll be left with what you want.

Comment: Btw, use `re.VERBOSE` instead of concatenating strings with `+` (in particular because the `+` sign is of course a special regex character, so things may be confusing to read).

Comment: thats a good idea, i will try it

Comment: Do you want to keep "Continue ..." between part2 and part3, or do you just want part2 and part3 by itself. Your example suggests the former, but your sentence "what I want are part2 and part3" suggests the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your text does not begin with "Continue ..." and does not end with "Continue ...", you can split on the "Continue ..." string, remove the first, last and empty items, and you'll be left with what you want.

```
import re
text = """\
part 1

Continue reading the main story

part 2

Continue reading the main story

part 3

Continue reading the main story

Continue reading the main story

part 4
"""

parts = re.split('Continue reading the main story', text)
print(parts)
# Ignore first and last part, test for and ignore
# empty (all whitespace) strings
innerparts = [part for part in parts[1:-1] if part.strip()]
print("".join(innerparts))
```

results in

```
part 2



part 3
```

(There's quite a few newlines, because that's how the input was. You can use `part.strip()` if you want to get rid of that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex. I'm using lookbehind and lookahead features:

```
rx = "(?<=part 1\n{2}Continue reading the main story).*(?=Continue reading the main story[\r\n]+part 4)"

for match in re.finditer(rx, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE):
    print(match.group().strip())
```

Based on your given text, it will print

```
part 2

Continue reading the main story

part 3

Continue reading the main story
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple re.findall() will do it.

```
rgx = r'Continue reading the main story(.*)Continue reading the main story'
match = re.findall(rgx, text, re.DOTALL)
if match:
    result = match[0].strip()
    print(result)
```

Based on your given text, this will print

```
part 2

Continue reading the main story

part 3

Continue reading the main story
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following pattern also:

```
import re
s = """
    part 1

    Continue reading the main story

    part 2

    Continue reading the main story

    part 3

    Continue reading the main story

    Continue reading the main story

    part 4
    """
print re.findall('(?:\s+Continue reading the main story\s\n)([\s\S]*?)(?:\n\s+Continue reading the main story\s){2}', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
part 2

Continue reading the main story

part 3
```